# Two constraints in single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl

My table contains a column named 'Email'. Now I want if someone provide an Email,SQL check the validation or if someone forgot to provide Email,SQL hold the default value 'None'.

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm definitely no DB expert but you could look into computed columns

Comment: Which database are you targetting?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure which database you are working on. This will work on Postgresql.

While creating the table, add constraint on the email column like this,

```
create table email_test 
(email text  check (email like '%@%.%' or email like 'NONE') default 'NONE');
```

If the table as been already created,

```
alter table email_test add constraint check_email check (email like '%@%%' or email like 'NONE');
```

But this ALTER will fail if there are any rows that violate the specified constraint.